# Why is Meteor using so much bandwidth? Is it Houston Admin Subscriptions?

Tags: node.js, meteor

Here is a strange scaling issue with Meteor. UNPUBLISHED collections seem to be affecting server usage. EDIT: This seems to be related to Houston Admin package.

REPRODUCE:
Here is the reproducible code: https://github.com/keyscores/houston_admin_performance_issue

SCENARIO A:
I started with a prototype app, which was aggregating/reducing 5 docs in 'db.originalData', into 1 doc in 'db.reducedResult'. The only collection published is the tiny 'reducedResult'. 
All this looks very efficient:

- 1% CPU usage
- 20mb ram allocated

SCENARIO B:
However, when I test real data with 15,000 records in originalData, *not*  published:

- 100% CPU is used
- 100% ram is used (1GB)
- Memory swapping to Disk
- 100% Bandwidth is used 10mb/S

This is strange because only the small collection * 1 record *  is published. The large collection, originalCollection, is unpublished.

---

Infrastructure:
The mongo server is on a separate server (compose.io) than the Meteor front end (Digital Ocean via MUP)

Comment: This seems odd. Do you have a [mcve] to demonstrate this issue? As your question currently stands answerers would have to guess what is happening.

Comment: Thanks Kyll, I did just add a link to the reproducible code. Requires some server set ups. I'm sure now it's related to Houston Admin.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like Houston Admin is using lots of CPU when connected to remote MongoDB instances.

Houston seems to create subscriptions on all collections, even those which might be *intentionally* hidden to the client (not published). It also seems occur on users which are not logged in. See the CPU timeline attached.

The problem is solved by removing Houston. The error also disappears when using a local mongo instance.

[image]

Issue cross posted here: 
https://github.com/keyscores/houston_admin_performance_issue

Comment: hii @LPG i'm interest with this issue.. how you conclude that `Houston makes subscriptions even for even subscriptions that are not published, and for users that are not logged in`..?? that's seems bad practice,, any reference code for this..?? thank You..

Comment: Hi @KarinaL if you run the code from github repo I created, there is a section called "Meteor Facts". This is a meteor tool that shows the number of subscriptions and other interesting info. I've noticed that with Houston Admin, the number of subscriptions (and listeners) is equal to the number of collections. With Houston uninstalled its equal to the number of subscriptions defined by you. So if one of your *unpublished*  collections has 1GB, it seems the meteor server will try to cache it.